# MIN Date within a single row

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, min

I am working on a query to provide the # of days a hiring process takes to complete.  The process starts with a release being provided by the candidate (Release Accepted) and ends with either a Final Offer or Rescind Date for employment.  I need to track those two dates in different fields so we can report on reasons for rescinded offers. Within the unique row - which is a specific candidate - which date comes first (Final Offer or Rescind Date.  Sometimes I may have both dates populated, we extend a final offer for employment and the candidate declines or fails to show for their first day of work.  However, to calculate the pace of days it takes to complete a background, I want the earliest date, final or rescind, which signifies the process is complete.

Hope that makes sense.

For instance, ReqNumber 1111 has 3 candidates for hire.  Candidate ID# 109 was provided a final offer on 01/02/2023, which ended their background process.  They did not show for work on 01/05/2023 so the offer was rescinded.  In order to calculate the number of workdays the background took to complete, I need DateDiff("d", [Hiring Process]![Release Accepted] , AND WHICHEVER DATE IS EARLIER BETWEEN FINAL AND RESCIND)

[image: Sample of Data for ReqNum 1111]

Note - I do not use SQL so please be kind =) and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Sample data should be provided as formatted text table, not image. If you don't use SQL then you never build queries in Access? Build expression with IIf(). `DateDiff("d", [Realease Accepted], IIf(Final_Offer< [Rescind Date], Final_Offer, [Rescind Date]))`. Strongly advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: Expression to handle Null: `DateDiff("d", [Release Accepted], IIf(Final_Offer<Nz([Rescind Date], Date()), Final_Offer, [Rescind Date]))`. Could a Rescind ever happen before an offer? Maybe just need: `DateDiff("d", [Release Accepted], Nz(Final_Offer, [Rescind Date]))`

Comment: Thank you both.  A rescind may happen before a final offer, usually when a candidate fails the background screening.   Also, my SQL abilities are limited to the query builder in Access - pretty novice compared to most of those I see in this platform.  Appreciate the help and advice overall!

Comment: And that's my point, how could Rescind ever have a date that is earlier than Offer date? Offer date would either be Null or earlier than Rescind. Did you try suggested expressions?

Comment: Currently the second and third options are working and  yield the same results.  We have evaluated our workflow and will ensure Rescinds to always occur before Final Offer.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use IIf() expression and since Final_Offer could be Null, use Nz() to deal with.

`DateDiff("d", [Release Accepted], IIf(Final_Offer<Nz([Rescind Date], Date()), Final_Offer, [Rescind Date]))`

Also, since I doubt Rescind could ever be dated before an offer (offer would be Null or dated before Rescind), maybe just:

`DateDiff("d", [Release Accepted], Nz(Final_Offer, [Rescind Date]))`